# topLayoutGuide messes up after UITableViewCell reuse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass in which I instantiate a `UIViewController` subclass and add it's `view` to the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`:

```
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentView.frame.size.width, contentView.frame.size.height)
contentView.addSubview(viewController.view)
```

Inside `viewController` (which is created as in a Storyboard), I have a `UIImageView` which is pinned to the top of the view (well, it's `topLayoutGuide`, since Xcode 6 Interface Builder seems to only allow me to pin to the `topLayoutGuide`, and not the container top edge anymore...)

I should also mention that the cell height is 230, which is the same size as `viewController.view` in Storyboard, so the `viewController` should take up the entire size of the cell.

This all works fine the first time the cell is displayed, but after reuse the `topLayoutGuide` in `viewController` seems to randomly mess up, causing the `UIImageView` no longer to be pinned to the top of the cell, and is instead shifted down:

**On the first display, `topLayoutGuide.length` is 0 which is correct. However, after scrolling up & down a bit, I can see in the cell's `prepareForReuse()` that `viewController.topLayoutGuide.length` changes to 179.333333333333 or 163.666666666667 which causes the whole cell layout to mess up.**

I can't figure out why `topLayoutGuide` is changing itself like this after cell reuse.

I suppose one workaround would be simply to pin the affected `UIImageView` to the top container edge rather than `topLayoutGuide`, which would sidestep this issue -- but it seems Xcode 6 no longer provides this functionality (at least, not without creating the constraints manually in code...)

This behaviour is exhibited in iOS 8, I've not tested other iOS versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to find out what the problem was, and why the `topLayoutGuide` was going weird after cell reuse, but I did manage to find out how to pin to the superview (container) bounds rather than the layout guides in Xcode 6, and this solved the issue.

In Interface Builder I used `Editor > Pin > Top Space to Superview` and this solved it for me.

Given that this option doesn't seem to exist anywhere else other than the menu options, it seems completely unintuitive, but that's Interface Builder for you...!

Comment: Pinning the top space to the superview is a regular constraint in the storyboard. Should be an option in the menus at the bottom right, or if you ctrl + drag from the view to its superview upwards.

Comment: It always used to be, but in Xcode 6.1 it seems to insist on pinning to "Top layout guide" even if I specifically select superview.

The only way I could find to force it to pin to the superview in Xcode 6 is via the Editor menu.

Comment: Depends on the positioning of the view. If you have a subview in the root view near the top, it will default to topLayoutGuide. You should be able to change it back though in the inspector. Will check it out and make sure.